# Exact Large Finite Field Linear Algebra Library (e.g. GF(2^128) / GF(2^256) )

Tags: c++, math, linear-algebra, computer-algebra-systems, finite-field

### General

I'm looking for a library that is able to do exact calculations on large finite fields such as GF(2<sup>128</sup>)/<sub>2<sup>128</sup></sub> and GF(2<sup>256</sup>)/<sub>2<sup>256</sup></sub>. I listed the features that I need and the features that would be cool below. Obviously, the library should be as fast as possible :-). Ah, since I'm no C++ master (and probably most of the libraries are C++), sample code of say *generate a random element/a constant and multiply it to it's multiplicative inverse*

### Must-Have Features

- Addition of field elements
- Multiplication of field element
- Find the multiplicative inverse of a field element

### Nice to Have Features

- Vector/Matrix support
- Random Element support

### Libraries I already looked at that will probably *not* work

- [FFLAS/FFPACK](http://www-ljk.imag.fr/membres/Jean-Guillaume.Dumas/FFLAS/), seems not to work with such large finite fields
- [Givaro](http://givaro.forge.imag.fr/), seems not to work on such large finite fields

### Libraries I already looked at that *could* work (but I was unable to use)

- <s>[NTL](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/), I was not able to invert an element, but it should really work since [SAGE](http://sagemath.org) seems to use this library when defining GF(2^256) and there an element can be inverted using `x^(-1)`</s>
- [PARI/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), I was not able to find everything I need in the documentation, but the SAGE documentation kind of says that it should work

### Other notes

- I'm writing a Haskell program and will interface that library later, so easier Haskell interfacing is better :-)

Comment: Have you looked into SAGE (http://www.sagemath.org/)?
I believe it does have that sort of functionality.

Comment: And it's got a python interface, which is (arguably) more pleasant to deal with than C++ :)

Comment: @Qnan Annoying multiplicative inverse seems to raise a NotImplementedError for finite fields. Although presumably one could implement the extended gcd algorithm ones self.

Comment: @cmh you mean the inverse_mod() thing?

Comment: Did you just look http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic ? there is a link to a c++ library from there http://www.partow.net/projects/galois/index.html but i don't know it's quality or efficiency

Comment: @Qnan, cool, I think SAGE seems to work: 
K = GF(2^256, 'c');
x = K.random_element();
x * x^-1;
--> 1

Comment: You can try posting on Computational Science SE (http://scicomp.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @ja72 , the problem is I'd need to cross-post this question which is usually not the way to go... I also did a quick search there and there are not too many Q/As involving linear algebra libraries...

Comment: In case you finished you Haskell program, can you share it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The NTL library seems to work, using this (sorry I'm quite unable to program in C++) code

```
#include <NTL/GF2E.h>
#include <NTL/GF2EX.h>
#include <NTL/GF2X.h>
#include <NTL/GF2XFactoring.h>

NTL_CLIENT

int main()
{
    GF2X P = BuildIrred_GF2X(256);
    GF2E::init(P);

    GF2E zero = GF2E::zero();
    GF2E one;
    GF2E r = random_GF2E();
    GF2E r2 = random_GF2E();
    conv(one, 1L);
    cout << "Cardinality: " << GF2E::cardinality() << endl;
    cout << "ZERO: " << zero << " --> " << IsZero(zero) << endl;
    cout << "ONE:  " << one  << " --> " << IsOne(one)   << endl;
    cout << "1/r:  " << 1/r  << ", r * (1/r): " << (r * (1/r)) << endl;
    cout << "1/r2:  " << 1/r2  << ", r2 * (1/r2): " << (r2 * (1/r2)) << endl;
}
```

it seems to work, proof (output of this program):

```
Cardinality: 115792089237316195423570985008687907853269984665640564039457584007913129639936
ZERO: [] --> 1
ONE:  [1] --> 1
1/r:  [0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1], r * (1/r): [1]
1/r2:  [1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 0 1 1 0 1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 1 1 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 1 1], r2 * (1/r2): [1]
```

Even inverting seems to work (scroll as right as possible in the output sample above) :-)